# Superset iframe always fixed to 300x150, cannot be changed

Tags: iframe, apache-superset

I am trying to embed an existing dashboard from Superset into a react application using the article at https://www.tetranyde.com/blog/embedding-superset. I am using the embedded SDK. Everything seems to be working fine except that the iframe is always fixed to 300x150 no matter what I try. I want it to use the available height and width.

[Superset iframe image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaTeK.png)

Here is my code:

```
const Dashboard = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    embedDashboard({
      id: dashboardId, // given by the Superset embedding UI
      supersetDomain: supersetDomain,
      mountPoint: document.getElementById("my-superset-container"), // any html element that can contain an iframe
      fetchGuestToken: () => fetchGuestTokenFromBackend(),
      dashboardUiConfig: {
        // dashboard UI config: hideTitle, hideTab, hideChartControls, filters.visible, filters.expanded (optional)
        hideTitle: true,
        filters: {
          expanded: false
        }
      }
    });
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <p>This is dashboard</p>

      <div
        id="my-superset-container"
        style={{ width: "100vw", height: "100vh" }}
      ></div>
    </div>
  );
};`
```

Even though I set width and height to 100vw/vh, I still see the actual superset Iframe set to 300x150.

Comment: Finally I was able to solve it myself. Just added  these two lines after the embeddashboard call within useEffect:
`
  //hack to make the view 100% in height and width
    document.getElementById("my-superset-container").children[0].width="100%";
    document.getElementById("my-superset-container").children[0].height="100%";
`